# Data Manipulation Function not passing test runs

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am working on the following problem and wrote my code to solve it. However, it does not pass the test run and I cannot figure out why. Here is the problem:

A company stores login data and password hashes in two different containers:

DataFrame with columns: Id, Login, Verified.
Two-dimensional NumPy array where each element is an array that contains: Id and Password.
Elements on the same row/index have the same Id.

Implement the function login_table that accepts these two containers and modifies id_name_verified DataFrame in-place, so that:

A. The Verified column should be removed.
B. The password from NumPy array should be added as the last column with the name "Password" to DataFrame.

```
For example, the following code snippet:

id_name_verified = pd.DataFrame([[1, "JohnDoe", True], [2, "AnnFranklin", False]], columns=["Id", "Login", "Verified"])
id_password = np.array([[1, 987340123], [2, 187031122]], np.int32)
login_table(id_name_verified, id_password)
print(id_name_verified)

Should print:
   Id        Login   Password
0   1      JohnDoe  987340123
1   2  AnnFranklin  187031122

Here is my code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def login_table(id_password,id_name_verified):
    a_df=pd.DataFrame(id_password)
    a_df.rename(columns={0:'Id',1:'Password'}, inplace=True)
    df_merge=pd.merge(a_df, id_name_verified, on='Id').drop('Verified', 1)
    master_df = df_merge[['Id', 'Login', 'Password']]
    return(master_df)
    pass



id_name_verified = pd.DataFrame([[1, "JohnDoe", True], 
                                 [2, "AnnFranklin", False]], 
                                columns=["Id", "Login", "Verified"])

id_password = np.array([[1, 987340123], 
                        [2, 187031122]], 
                       np.int32)

login_table(id_password,id_name_verified)

Here is the Hint Message: Passwords from NumPy array can be extracted with id_password[...,1]....what does this mean?
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing 'inplace=True' inside the function, you will be able to modify the id_name_verified as a global variable.

```py
def login_table(id_name_verified, id_password):
    id_name_verified.drop(['Verified'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    id_name_verified['Password']=id_password[:,1]
    pass
id_name_verified = pd.DataFrame([[1, "JohnDoe", True], [2, "AnnFranklin", False]], columns=["Id", "Login", "Verified"])
id_password = np.array([[1, 987340123], [2, 187031122]], np.int32)
login_table(id_name_verified, id_password)
print(id_name_verified)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def login_table(id_name_verified, id_password):

id_name_verified["Password"]=id_password[:,1]
id_name_verified=id_name_verified.drop("Verified",axis=1)  

return id_name_verified

id_name_verified = pd.DataFrame([[1, "JohnDoe", True], [2, "AnnFranklin",False]], columns=["Id", "Login", "Verified"])

id_password = np.array([[1, 987340123], [2, 187031122]], np.int32)
id_name_verified=login_table(id_name_verified, id_password)

print(id_name_verified)
```